# How do I install Cassandra 4 RPM package when only Java 11 is installed?

Tags: java, cassandra, rpm, cassandra-4.0

Cassandra 4 should work with java 11, but when I try to install it without java 8 then the installation fails:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    jre >= 1.8.0 is needed by cassandra-4.0.4-1.noarch
```

How can I get around this?
My current workaround is to install both java 8 and java 11, that way I satisfy the dependency requirement and can run cassandra 4 with java 11. However, there must surly be a better way?
I would of course prefer to only have java 11 installed.

Some extra info:

I use CentOs 7 and RHEL 8

Cassandra rpm downloaded from https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/redhat/40x/

```
 java -version
     openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 LTS
     OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS)
     OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Effective Cassandra 4.0.2 there is full Java 11 support, it is not experimental anymore.

Ref: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/new/java11.html

Comment: Yet, with cassandra 4.04 which I am trying to install here it fails because of a dependency on java 8? That's why I am confused, java 11 doesn't have a jre and will never meet the dependency requirement as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JRE is no longer available in Java 11 ([JDK 11 release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html)):

> In this release, the JRE or Server JRE is no longer offered. Only the JDK is offered.

we probably shouldn't require the [JRE as a dependency](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/redhat/cassandra.spec#L49) on CentOS and RHEL platforms:

```
Requires:      jre >= 1.8.0
```

As a workaround, you can override the dependency check when installing the RPM with the `--nodeps` option. For example:

```
$ sudo rpm --nodeps -i cassandra-4.0.4-1.noarch.rpm
```

In the meantime, I've logged [CASSANDRA-17669](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17669) for resolution. Cheers!